# Research-level blogs on complex networks:

Tags: graph-theory, big-list, applied-mathematics, complex-networks

I'm an applied mathematician that has a research interest in complex networks for modelling biological systems and I wondered whether the MathOverflow community might know of research-level blogs that cover 
topics concerning complex networks and/or graph theory. Ideally, these blogs would cover models of complex networks and methods for controlling such networks.

After consulting Réka Albert, Igor Pak, Scott Aaronson, Lance Fortnow and Tai-Danae Bradley 
I have the following list of network scientists and/or graph-theory researchers that put a lot of 
work into science communication:

1. Mason Porter: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~mason/
2. Albert-László Barabási: https://www.barabasilab.com/
3. Gil Kalai: https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/

But I haven’t found something similar in purpose to [Terrence Tao’s blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/) or the [n-category cafe](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/).

Comment: Start a blog and seed it with material you would like to see. In a few weeks, check a search engine for more material like your blog. Gerhard "Get Machines To Tell You" Paseman, 2019.08.23.